# AngularJS controller not a function in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst

AngularJS controller not a function in IBM MobileFirst is what I am getting an error. I went through many similar questions being ask on Stack Overflow but nothing helped me.

[Error Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaxlR.jpg)

```js
// **************** app.js ***************

var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
 
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
 
 $stateProvider
  .state('login',{
   url:'/login',
   templateUrl:'view/login.html',
   controller:'loginController'
  });
 
});


// **************** login.js ***************


app.controller('loginController',function($scope){
 
 $scope.login = function(){
  $scope.userName = angular.element('#usrName').val();
  $scope.password = angular.element('#pass').val();
  console.log($scope.userName, $scope.password);
  
  
  
  $scope.loginProcedure ={
    procedure:'login',
    adaptor:'SQL',
    parameters:[$scope.userName, $scope.password]
  };
  
  WL.Client.invokeProcedure($scope.loginProcedure, function(){
   onSuccess: loginSuccess,
   onFailure: loginFailure
  });
  
  $scope.loginSuccess = function()
  {
   alert('success');
  };
  
  $scope.loginFailure = function()
  {
   alert('failed');
  };
 }
 
});
```

```html
<!-- INDEX.html -->

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>AB</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
      <!--
       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
       <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
      -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
      
      <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
     </head>
     <body ng-app="myApp">
      <!--application UI goes here-->
      
      <div id="view" ui-view></div>
      
      <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
      <script src="library/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="library/angular.1.4.9.js"></script>
      <script src="library/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
      <script src="library/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="controller/app.js"></script>
      <script src="controller/login.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>

<!-- Login.html --> 

<div ng-controller="loginController" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 center-block" id="lgBlock">

 <!-- Login Box Start -->

 <div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <form class="form-group" name="lgForm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrName" ng-modal="usrName" required />
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" ng-modal="pass" required />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit" value="Login" ng-click="login()" />
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <!-- Login Box End -->
 
 <!--  error Modal start -->
 
 <div class="modal" role="modal" id="errorPopup">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">Error</div>
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <!--  error Modal End -->

</div>
```

Comment: There is an error on line 18 of login.js according to your Print Screen. Can you resolve this to see if it helps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was wrong spelling of adapter

```js
 /* wrong one */

$scope.loginProcedure ={
    procedure:'login',
    adaptor:'SQL',
    parameters:[$scope.userName, $scope.password]
  };


/*write one */

$scope.loginProcedure ={
    procedure:'login',
    adapter:'SQL',
    parameters:[$scope.userName, $scope.password]
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying loginController in your html as well as in your route configuration. I'm not certain that this is the cause of the problem, but doing both is unnecessary. Remove one of them.

In other words, eliminate controller: 'loginController' from below

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login',{
        url:'/login',
        templateUrl:'view/login.html',
        controller:'loginController'
    });
```

or eliminate: ng-controller="loginController" from:

```
<div ng-controller="loginController" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 center-block" id="lgBlock">
```

Also, unrelated, but I doubt that these two lines:

```
$scope.userName = angular.element('#usrName').val();
$scope.password = angular.element('#pass').val();
```

do what you think. The purpose of angular.element is to wrap elements as jquery elements. I suspect you want to use document.getElementById here to get references to the items. However, you're using ngModel here, so none of this should be necessary if you use consistent spelling. (In one place you have userName and in another usrName.)

Comment: Which of the below one is correct

1) $scope.login = function($scope.userName, $scope.password){

parameters : [$scope.userName, $scope.password]

2) $scope.login = function(userName, password){

parameters : [userName, password]

Comment: Comments aren't the place for this. I'd suggest getting the controller loading issue resolved, then opening a new question. You have a lot of issues in your html and your controller. Sorry that I sort of lead you down that path. Did removing one of the controller references solve the first issue?